# How to Connect Bezier Curves in Inkscape?

Tags: vector, inkscape

[image]

You can see there two bezier curves that I want to connect together. How can I do that? My current area with the peak consists of many small bezier curves which is totally intolerable because it makes the processing of the picture much harder later.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Joining curves (in Inkscape called "Paths") is really simple:

1. select both paths with "edit paths" tool (F2). You can do it by clicking on one of them, and then holding shift and clicking another.
2. select two nodes you want to join by drawing a selection rectangle around them.
   [image: selecting two nodes on different paths]
3. Select one of the options to join: either "join selected nodes" into one (which will be in the middle of the selected ones):
   [image: joining nodes directly]

either "join selected nodes with a straight segment" - which will retain the points, and join them with a segment:
[image: joining nodes with straight segment]

Comment: You can use this technique for as many nodes as you want to join together. Just select all of them and click "Joint selected nodes" once. You don't have to do them one by one!

Answer (score 21):

I wanted to expand on Justinas's answer. You cannot join non-endnodes in Inkscape due to the SVG spec. So you cannot create a path that forms a T intersection, although you can simulate it by using Path-Combine or Group.

See [http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=10362](https://web.archive.org/web/20160306001118/http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=10362)

PS : SVG spec mandates that a node can only connect to two adjacent nodes, hence T or X intersections where > 2 nodes connect to the central node is not possible.

Comment: Thank you so much Neil - just been trying to figure this out for the last hour!

Comment: If you want a T intersection you just need to select *snap to paths* and the bezier curve will snap to the path

Comment: Thankyou so much! Path-Combine is so useful! `ctrl + k`