# How to join end nodes of different paths in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, path

I've been working recently on 3D printing TSP maps. I've included a pretty simple sample right here:

[image: Zebra TSP Map]

The issue is that when I try to manipulate this figure, it recognizes it as 25 separate sections. I thought that there may have been some node limit per object, but as it turns out, some of the sections were not properly joined (I only discovered this around 25000% zoom)

[image]

The end node shown is in the EXACT same position as the end node of the adjacent object not highlighted, but they are definitely different. (I can move each independently) I don't know how to join them, and the research I've done hasn't yielded much...I don't mind fixing it, but I don't know how.

Comment: Have you tried the approaches listed in [this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7343/how-to-connect-bezier-curves-in-inkscape)?

Comment: beautiful graphic! - would you mind telling how did you produce this?

Answer (score 13):

You can join the two paths using node tool.

1. Select both the paths using node tool.

   [image: Image2]
2. Select the two nodes at the joint and click on the "Join selected nodes" icon from the control bar as shown

   [image: Image3]

Now the two nodes at the joint are connected to form a single node.

Comment: You can use this technique for as many nodes as you want to join together. Just select all of them and click "Joint selected nodes" once. You don't have to do them one by one!

Comment: In case you have the nodes of the two pieces one over the other, just select with a a rectangle selection instead of trying to click on each node.