# Inkscape: connect cloned Bezier curves

Tags: inkscape, bezier-curve

I'm trying to connect two Bezier curves in Inkscape. As [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7343/how-to-connect-bezier-curves-in-inkscape) suggests, it is possible to use the edit-paths tool for this.

However, of the two Bezier curves I am trying to connect, one of the two is a clone of the other (which means I cannot use the edit-paths tool on it, it simply does not recognize the points within).

I want to still be able to edit the original, and see how the result looks when applied to all clones, however I want several clones to have their endpoints connected with a path. Is there another way I can go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify a cloned path, you first have to delink the clone. This way, you lose the central feature of clones you are interested in. Depending on what exactly you want to do, the following alternatives may be feasible:

- If you do not want to modify the end points of the cloned paths, you can create a third path to connect the two clones. The easiest way to do this is arguably by employing *snapping to cusp/smooth nodes.*
- If the connecting path is in the same relative position to one of the clones, you can make it part of the clone. This way you only have to apply one small additional manual fix for some steps.

Comment: Using snapping is pretty doable for most purposes. Thank you for the clear explanation!