# Connect a circle and a line together

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, affinity-designer

I want to connect a path to a circle so that when I move the circle, the path will follow automatically. I can't just merge the shape together, since that *wouldn't* allow for the circle to have seperate properties (such as color) from the line.

Right now when I move the circle, I have to adjust the path myself which is annoying.

[image: The example behavior that I want to achieve.]

Is it possible to do that? I could be either on Adobe Illustrator or Affinity Designer.

PS. I have tried to search this before asking but I don't know the keywords so the search results didn't satisfy my need. I only found [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/109416/dynamically-adjusting-line-between-nodes-of-objects-in-inkscape) but it's Inkscape.

Comment: Yoi can not they are too direct modellers to do this.

Answer (score 11):

In Illustrator, it's actually quite simple and easy.

Use the *Direct Selection Tool* (<kbd>A</kbd>) to select the *whole* area around the circle (including the anchor points from the lines)

Then just drag it to the desired area.

See GIF below:

[image]

---

You have to use the Direct Selection Tool as opposed to the regular one, because the regular one will select full paths, you just want to select anchors themselves.

---

Another example:

[image]

Comment: That works also in Affinity Designer. 2 differences: 1) The circles must be converted to curves before 2) You must select the shapes that you are going to modify. After it you can select the nodes with the node tool by dragging. The node tool doesn't see the nodes of unselected shapes. Remember to lock the shapes that you want to stay intact.

Comment: @user287001 this method (with your additional proviso) also works in Inskscape. It's probably also possible in other vector image editing software - as long as there is a tool that can select multiple nodes and they are selectable, you should be able to move them all as one unit.

Comment: Serial voting honestly

Comment: @CalvT now [click here](http://bit.ly/2QRzVWf) once you have a *Red Santa Hat hat*.

Answer (score -1):

**For Adobe Illustrator**

If your intent is to move multiple objects, select the objects and press ctrl-G or right click one of them and select group.

This will allow you to move all the objects in the group at the same time without having to select them individually. It also allows for each object to have individual properties like color and stroke for example.

If you want to edit an object in the group, double click the object. This will move you down a step in the hierarchy allowing you to edit group members individually without affecting all of them. Once finished double click outside to return to normal view.

An added bonus, in the layers tab you can name the group to organize your scene.

Comment: I don't think that this would achieve what the OP is talking about.

Comment: @WELZ The OP said that he/she wanted to move two objects without changing the distance between them, therefore moving both at the same time. Grouping will do just that as it will move the group members as one object than individual ones when editing.

Comment: I think that they want to be able to move around the circles and have the lines stay *connected* and also get moved around (like I showed in my answer)

Comment: @WELZ a group will do exactly that. It won't change the distance between group members, therefore, the path will stay connected to the circle while being moved with it.