# Joining paths in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

How do you join paths in Inkscape?

For instance, use paths to draw a trapezoid. I would like to join the opposite corners with a 5th and a 6th line, so that each of the 4 nodes has three lines connecting it. How to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Connect Bezier Curves in Inkscape?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7343/how-to-connect-bezier-curves-in-inkscape)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  The answer below answers my question pretty well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a branch (a node with more than two segments) in a path, due to a limitation of SVG specification, to which inkscape is strictly adherent: **a node can only connect to two adjacent nodes**.

You can *simulate* the effect by drawing two lines and combining or grouping them.

See [this post on Inkscapeforum.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20160306001118/http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=10362) and [this answer on Graphicdesign.stackexchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7343/how-to-connect-bezier-curves-in-inkscape).

If you need a more specific tool, you can can use something like [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org), which is also able to export to SVG.

Comment: It's not just in Inkscape, and not only an SVG limitation. It's also not possible to join a path to the anchors of a closed path in Adobe Illustrator. In fact, it's probably not possible in any 2D vector image editing software.

Comment: I agree, but the question was related to Inkscape. There are some tools specific for network or for topology which manage such a kind of situation without involving connectors, but I don't dare to classify them as vector image editing software. And of course in 3D tools a vertex can join multiple edges.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, especially for pointing out it is a limitation of SVG and not just Inkscape.  It seems like such a fundamentally reasonable thing to want to do.  I believe your suggestion of combining them will do what I want to do. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jack - actually, fundamentally it's not a reasonable thing to want to do in 2D vector software. A vector, by definition, has either a start and end point (an open path), or is a closed path (such as a trapezoid). So, if you think about it, vectors can only be joined at their start/end points.  A closed path has no start and end point, so there's nothing to join it to.  Welcome to the crazy world of vectors!