# How to connect three different nodes into one in an Inkscape?

Tags: vector, inkscape, svg, merge

I know that I cannot join non-endnodes in Inkscape due to the SVG spec.

I know how to join two different nodes into one merged one ( [How to Connect Bezier Curves in Inkscape?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7343/how-to-connect-bezier-curves-in-inkscape) ).

But how can I join three end point of this

[image]

into a single end point? I want to be able to move either entire line, or just shared node without breaking T junction apart.

I even tried selecting separate color for each way, but it seems impossible to merge nodes without merging lines.

To avoid XY-problem: I want to make lines between other lines that reach them exactly. Neither going farther, neither going too close. SVG image will be send to a laser cutter, so I prefer to be 100% exact.

In addition I want to keep further modification easy. I want to be able to move grouped object and move all attached ways with it, stretching them as needed.

I thought that I can achieve this by merging nodes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't join 3 end nodes together. It's not possible. You can only join 2. It's not because of the SVG format, it's because a vector can only have two end nodes, i.e. a start and an end point.

Perhaps you could enable snapping to achieve exact placement of the nodes.

[image]

Once placed, you could select all the end nodes and move as one, but there's no way to group or merge 3 end nodes.

Comment: How did you manage to create the gif?

Comment: @Adriano I used screen capture software called ShareX, which has a GIF recording function.

Comment: Cheers, mate!   :)

Comment: "it's because a vector can only have two end nodes, i.e. a start and an end point" Lets say that we have ways A, B, C and nodes N1, N2, N3, NS. way A leading from N1 to NS, way B leading N2 to NS, way C leading from N3 to NS has shared node NS and each vector has a start node and an end node. I am not saying that it is possible, but it seems to not be the reason.

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny There's no such thing as a "shared node" in Inkscape. You seem to be trying to come up with some method that doesn't exist to solve a problem you don't know how to solve. To be honest, that would seem to be the definition of an XY Problem which you said you were trying to avoid.

Comment: Would it be correct to change "because a vector can only have two end nodes, i.e. a start and an end point" into "because each node can belong to no more than a singe vector"?

Comment: The reason is rather simple @MateuszKonieczny its as complicated as it needs to be, but no more complicated. The reason not each bezier is standalone is filling areas with color. For this reason you need to be able to chain beziers to polybeziers. You also need compound pathsto be able to do holes. But thats it since to draw a y branch you do not need a connection they dont model it thatway.